# lsnrctl not found in Ubuntu 14.04LTs after Oracle 11g installation

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

I am trying to run SQL*Plus to start my database but I keep getting errors:

```
oracle@ictd23:~$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 26 15:52:37 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle. All rights reserved.

SQL> startup
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

oracle@ictd23:~$ sqlplus system@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 26 16:02:14 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

When I try to start the listener I also get an error:

```
oracle@ictd23:~$ lsnrctl start
lsnrctl: command not found.
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Have you set up your environment properly? What exactly did you install - the server or client software? (Since you can apparently see `sqlplus` but not `lsnrctl` I'm guessing you only installed the client). The SQL\*Plus error suggests you're trying to connect to a remote database, so showing what you're actually trying to execute might be useful; if the database is on a different machine you'd need to check/start the listener on that anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole I installed the client. thsi is what am executing                          oracle@ictd23:~$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 26 15:52:37 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> startup
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Comment: So which database are you trying to access and start up? Do you have a `tnsnames.ora` entry for `orcl`, and what is that pointing to? Installing the client doesn't create a database, you need the server software before you can create one, but you might be trying to connect to one that does already exist elsewhere. Is suspect not though.

Comment: oracle@ictd23:~$ sqlplus system@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 26 16:02:14 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Answer (score 2):

Most probably lsnrctl command is not in the PATH (either because your shell environment is not set for oracle), try command as below

```
$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start
```

Or set the environment using coraenv or oraenv scripts and check if $ORACLE_HOME/bin is present in your PATH

```
# For cshell
% source /usr/local/bin/coraenv
% lsrnctl start

# For other shell (eg. bash/sh/k-shell)
$ . /usr/local/bin/oraenv
$ lsnrctl start
```

Comment: The OP has said they only installed the client; plus if they are picking up `sqlplus` from the PATH then they'd be able to see `lsnrctl` too?

Answer (score 0):

See that `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME` are set properly. You can set using the below eg:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1;
export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=oracle; 
export ORACLE_SID
```

Comment: If ORACLE_HOME wasn't set the OP would get a message file error, and ORACLE_SID isn't needed as they're using a connection string, `@orcl`. The OP has said they only installed the client, which seems to be the root of the problem - there doesn't seem to be a database to connect to or start.